# Run a shutdown script with the option to abort shutdown

Tags: windows, shutdown

I would like a popup message to display when a user tries to shutdown the computer, to remind him to do a certain job. It will have two buttons, one of which should be able to abort the shutdown process.
I found this:

```
<job id="vbs">
<script language="VBScript">
Set WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
On Error Resume Next
menuSel=MsgBox("Have you completed your time sheet?", vbYesNo)
If menuSel=vbYes Then
WshShell.Run "Shutdown -a"
End If
</script>
</job>
```

I saved it as ShutdownReminder.wsf and went to gpedit.msc computer configuration -> windows settings -> Scripts -> Shutdown and added it on the list

I also went to administrative templates -> System -> Scirpts and Enabled the "Run shutdown scripts visible" option.

The problem is that although the popup message appears, none of the two options disables the shutdown process. Is there anything I can do to fix that?

O.S. Windows 7 x64